# DataFormatString for DateTime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetime-format

I'm trying to apply a format in a DateTime attribute but it is not working. I have this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DataInscricao { get; set; }
```

I've tried to do it in many ways (changing the DataFormatString) but none of them are working. I'm also using datepicker for my Date fields.

I also tried to apply the format from jQuery:

```
$("#DataInscricao").datepicker( {dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
```

It almost works, the format is applied in the TextBox but when I try to Save the date format is lost. If I enter a date like 12/01/2013, it changes to 01/01/0001. In the GridView the format is different (mm-dd-yyyy) and the mask of the TextBox is working wrong.

I really don't know what to do to make it work. Is there someone who can help me with this issue?

Thanks!

UPDATE

This is the method in the Controller which returns the entity to edit.

```
public ActionResult Editar(int id)
{
    var agendamento = _repository.GetSingle(a => a.Id == id);
    return View("Criar", agendamento);
}
```

And this is the View:

```
@model PNCQ2013.Domain.Entities.AgendamentoManutencao
@{
    ViewBag.Title = PNCQ2013.Domain.Resources.ItemPatrimonio.ItemPatrimonio.TitleAgendamento + " :: PNCQ - Programa Nacional de Controle de Qualidade";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="section">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Salvar", "ManutencaoPreventiva", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", LoadingElementId = "loading" }, new { @class = "formee", @id = "frmAgendamentoManutencao", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    <div class="box">
        <div class="title">
            @PNCQ2013.Domain.Resources.ItemPatrimonio.ItemPatrimonio.TitleAgendamento
        </div>
        <div class="content nopadding">
            <div class="grid-4-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ItemPatrimonioId)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ItemPatrimonioId, new SelectList(PNCQ2013.Web.Content.Helpers.Util.ListaItemPratrimonio().OrderBy(a => a.NumeroPatrimonio), "Id", "NumeroPatrimonio"), Resources.Geral.Selecione)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ItemPatrimonioId)
            </div>
            <div class="grid-4-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DataInscricao)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DataInscricao, new { @class = "datepicker" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DataInscricao)
            </div>
            <div class="grid-4-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FrequenciaManutencaoId)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FrequenciaManutencaoId, PNCQ2013.Web.Content.Helpers.HtmlExtensions.ToSelectList(typeof(PNCQ2013.Domain.Enumerators.FrequenciaManutencao), ""), Resources.Geral.Selecione)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FrequenciaManutencaoId)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: It sounds like there's a problem assigning the date from the string in the `TextBox` to the `DateTime`, rather than an issue with formatting, you'd expect a formatting problem to set it to something like 01/12/2013.  Can you post the view and the controller code?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DataInscricao { get; set; }
```

Comment: @Sravan, This doesn't work for the edit/create view.